# What is the name of perfomance technique used in the chorus of Celldweller -- Last Firstborn?

Tags: technique, terminology, performing, electronic-music

I am currently obsessed with the track by [Celldweller](http://www.last.fm/music/Celldweller) called "Last Firstborn".  Is there any name for the keyboard technique used in the chorus?

In this YouTube video you can hear it from 1:28 right until 1:57:

---

Edit: If it's not some particular *technique* with keyboard itself, then it has to be some *synthesizer effect* (it's an 50/50 electronic music after all) and identifying its name will be sufficient to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a rapid arpeggio - most synths these days will auto-arpeggiate sets of chords you play in.

The Access Virus synth does this quite well. I couldn't find the video sample I was looking for, but [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TL4C3rSYN8E) should give an example.